# Fairplay implementation in Swift, AVAssetResourceDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer, fairplay

I watched Apple FairPlay introduction videos, I read a this code:
https://gist.github.com/fousa/5709fb7c84e5b53dbdae508c9cb4fadc
And I also went through HLS Catalog from apple and with the last the problem is that I need only playing DRM videos without any downloading and all this stuff so I started from GitHub example.
I have a certificate, videos in FairPlay and the key server module.
My first and main problem is that AVResourceDelegate isn't calling when I'm giving AVURLAsset with video url. I read at stack that I need to change scheme to sth else, e.g "DRM" from https and right AVResourceDelegate calling then but I don't have .m3u8 file because video link is wrong!
Could you please guys/girls help me.

```
import Foundation
import AVKit
import NotificationCenter

public struct DRMVideoData{
   var drmKey: String?
   var proxyFairPlay: String
   var fileFairPlay: String
   var idVideo: String
}

class VODDRMImplementation: NSObject, AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate {

let domain = "DRMDelegate.ContentKeyQueue"
let contentKeyDelegateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "DRMDelegate.ContentKeyQueue")

var drmData: DRMVideoData?

func startPlayerWithDRM(_ videoDRM: DRMVideoData,_ player: AVPlayer?,_ playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?, c: @escaping (AVPlayer?, AVPlayerLayer?) -> Void) {

    var urlcomp = URLComponents(string: videoDRM.fileFairPlay)

    urlcomp?.scheme = "drm"

    if let url = try? urlcomp?.asURL(){

        self.drmData = videoDRM

        let url = url

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url!)
        asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: self.contentKeyDelegateQueue)

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        player.pause()

        c(player, playerLayer)
    }else{
        c(nil, nil)
    }

    }

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
    log.debug("DRM: started")

    // getting data for KSM server
    guard let urlToConvert = loadingRequest.request.url,
        let drmData = drmData else {
            log.debug("DRM: unable to read URL from loadingRequest")
            loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: NSError(domain: domain, code: -1, userInfo: nil))
            return false
    }

    do{

        log.debug("DRM: video link \(urlToVideo)")

        guard let certificateData = getCertificateFromServer() else {
                log.debug("DRM: false to get public certificate")
                loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: NSError(domain: domain, code: -3, userInfo: nil))
                return false
        }

        let contentId = drmData.idVideo // content id
        guard let contentIdData = contentId.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let spcData = try? loadingRequest.streamingContentKeyRequestData(forApp: certificateData, contentIdentifier: contentIdData, options: nil),
            let dataRequest = loadingRequest.dataRequest else {
                loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: NSError(domain: domain, code: -3, userInfo: nil))
                log.debug("DRM: false to get SPC Data from video")
                return false
        }

        let ksmServer = URL(string: drmData.proxyFairPlay)! // KSM link
        var request = URLRequest(url: ksmServer)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.httpBody = spcData
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                log.debug("DRM: unable to fetch ckc key :/")
                loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: NSError(domain: self.domain, code: -4, userInfo: nil))
                return
            }
            dataRequest.respond(with: data)
            loadingRequest.finishLoading()
        }
        task.resume()

    }catch{
        loadingRequest.finishLoading(with: NSError(domain: domain, code: -3, userInfo: nil))
        log.debug("DRM: cannot generate url to video")
        return false
    }


    return true


}

func takeURLFromId(_ videoLink: String) -> URL{
    let urlString = videoLink
    let url = URLComponents(string: urlString)
    do{
        let urlToReturn = try url?.asURL()
        guard let urlToReturn2 = urlToReturn else {
            let error = NSError(domain: domain, code: 0, userInfo: nil)
            throw error }
        return urlToReturn2
    }catch{
        if let url = NSURL(string: videoLink){
            return url as URL
        }else{
            return NSURL(string: videoLink)! as URL
        }
    }

}

func getCertificateFromServer() -> Data?{
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "privatekey", ofType: "pem")

    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: filePath!)!) else {
        return nil
    }

    return data
}

}
```

Comment: Hi , Did you get the solution , if yes then please share the answer

Comment: @pkesaj did you get the answer?

Comment: @RaviOjha have you solved the issue?

Comment: @AmritTiwari   Sorry. i didn't get the solution

Comment: Are you testing on device or simulator?  Unfortunately you will only get the shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource callback when running on device.  Also if you are looking for good test streams you can find valid .m3u8 files under "FairPlay Streaming Test Streams" on the apple developer site:   https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/

Comment: @pkesaj Did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the line:

`player.pause()` to `player.play()`

Also I think keeping a reference to the player in your class should help, like so:

```
var player: AVPlayer?
```